# Can't print month value from dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, dictionary, mode

I am trying to print the month name from this dictionary which is defined well before the code:

```
month_index = { '1': 'January',
                '2': 'February',
                '3': 'March',
                '4': 'April',
                '5': 'May',
                '6': 'June'}
```

I try to access the element using `dataframe.mode()` from some dataframe that outputs multiple columns one of which produces a month column where the values are only 1,2,3,4,5, or 6, representing January to June. `dataframe.mode` is producing `0    6` where 6 = June.

```
common_month = df['month'].mode()
        if common_month in month_index:
            print('The most common month is ', month_index, '.')
```

Should I create a dictionary with the results from `.mode()` or just use `df['month'].mode().str[1]` then use `in` to access value in the month_index? Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it now, it is checking the dict keys for `common_month`, but you need to check the values. Also I'm assuming you want to print only the most common month, not the whole dictionary. Just change the if statement to this.

```
if common_month in month_index.values():
            print(f'The most common month is {common_month}.')
```

Comment: It is not printing the value. The dataframe is not the month_index. I am referring to another dataframe where the ```dataframe.mode()``` is churning out that ``` 6``` (which is June) but not printing

Comment: It worked once I adjusted what I wanted my ```common_month``` to equal. Instead, ```common_month = df['month'].mode()[0]
  if common_month in month_index: 
   print('\nThe most common month is', month_index[common_month])```

Comment: It would help in the future if you added the output of for example `common_month = df['month'].mode()`, because we have no idea what your dataframe looks like, so it would be easier to understand what you need.

Comment: I will. I do apologize if it is unclear. Past questions I asked was giving too much information so I'm still learning how to format and ask properly. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The mode() function will `returning object pandas.core.series.Series` data type. And you're not checking the dict values. So you must using any/all in common_month, get the index, and check the values in dict.

```
if common_month.any() in month_index.values():
    print('The most common month is', common_month[0], '.')
```